# Ruby on Rails & Bootstrap: Trying to resize an image in my view file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, resize, size, bootstrapping

This image is appearing when on my local server but I am looking for it to fill the page. I'm working on a ruby on rails project and I've installed bootstrap-sass to it.

Can you please tell me how I can make this image fill the webpage? The image is appearing on half of the page. What I've tried below doesn't seem to work.

```
<html>

<head>
<!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="..assets/stylesheets/background.css" type="text-css">-->
</head>

<body>  
<%= link_to image_tag( 'logo.png'),'Options', :size => "400*400"%>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Rails syntax little different in resizing image. Try this one this should help you. Rails [Doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html#method-i-image_tag-label-Examples)

```
<%= image_tag('logo.png', :size => "260x180") %>
```

if you want it clickable.

```
<%= link_to image_tag('logo.png', :size => "260x180"), URL_HERE %>
```

Comment: Thanks that works but the image is no longer linked to my next page. The image should be a clickable image that brings users to the next page.

Comment: @shellmaster Updated the post